# Listening to edit events using ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, events

I recently started working on ArcMap.
I want to make some changes to the edit tools.

For example, I want to prevent the user from using the sketch tool when the time is between 1pm and 2pm but I don't know where to start.

Does anyone have a simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all necessary info and samples in this help topic: [Working with editing events](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Working_with_editing_events/000100000154000000/).

> The editor provides a rich set of events for developers to listen and
> respond to, ensuring that editing customizations remain synchronized
> with the editor environment and provide a consistent and logical user
> experience.